# Does the "editorWhitespace.foreground" workbench.colorCustomizations setting in VSCode actually work?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using version 1.13 of VSCode on the Mac. I'd like to override the theme colour for whitespace. Following the docs:

> editorWhitespace.foreground: Color of whitespace characters in the
>   editor.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference.md

I have put this in the settings:

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorWhitespace.foreground": "#333",
    "editorIndentGuide.background": "#333"
  }
```

The "editorIndentGuide.background" has an effect, but "editorWhitespace.foreground" doesn't. Am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE: To clarify, when the whitespace is visible the spaces are indicated with white dots. I'm expecting to be able to change the colour of the dots to, say, #333 with the "editorWhitespace.foreground" setting.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does for me on Windows 10.  I assume you have "Toggle Render Whitespace" under View menu on?  What color is your editor background, perhaps it is too close to #333 to appear obvious.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answering. Yes, I have Toggle Render Whitespace available under the View menu and it works fine.

Comment: ... and I have tried many garish colour schemes trying to get this to work :) Actually the issue is: when the whitespace is visible the spaces are indicated with white dots. I'm expecting to be able to change the colour of the dots to, say, #333 with the "editorWhitespace.foreground" setting.

Comment: I added a picture of most of my colorCustomizations - you can see editorWhitespace.foregoround working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with this when specifically using the Default High Contrast theme. This has been fixed with the August 2017 release.