# Change the color of special characters in VS Code?

Tags: colors, special-characters, whitespace, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I would like to highlight any tab characters that appear in my code in bright red as I prefer to use spaces only.

I have the render whitespace setting enabled, and I have looked through the [Theme Color](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors) configurations, but I am not seeing anything that I can set relating to special characters.

Is there any way currently to add this customization?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665595/does-the-editorwhitespace-foreground-workbench-colorcustomizations-setting-in `"editorWhitespace.foreground": "#f00",` in your `colorCustomizations`

Comment: Unfortunately, this highlights all whitespace characters. I am only interested in highlighting tab characters.

Comment: maybe try extension Highlight https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm..thanks @rioV8!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by rioV8, the method to do this is to use the [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) extension for VS Code and add this to your settings.json:

```
"highlight.regexes": {
    "(\\t)": [
        {
            "color": "red"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

On the menu bar, which is the row of menus such as File and Edit, choose Tools > Options.
On the Environment > General options page, change the Color theme selection to Dark, and then choose OK. The color theme for the entire Visual Studio development environment (IDE) changes to Dark.

Comment: I am already using a dark theme- this doesn't really address my specific question sorry.